# Include marko templates into the same component

Tags: javascript, marko

I have a marko (we use version `4.7.4`) component (component.js and index.marko file) whose markup I'd like to split across multiple files. I don't want to split them out into different components and I want them to access the same component definition.

I tried using `<include('path/to/template.marko') />` which did include the markup but the component functions where not accessible from inside this template.

Something like `component.myFunction()` didn't work.
Am I doing something wrong here? The goal is to simply split the markup across multiple files but using one component.

Comment: Please share your template code. Generally, you _do_ want to split things by making them separate components.

Comment: Think of a form with multiple tabs or accordions or areas that all contribute to the same form data.

Comment: Still ... each of those can be divided into their various parts, and still be done with relatively little code in the children (just bubble all the events you need). I'm pretty certain you'll find that building separate components is the only solution for what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I came to the same conclusion @seangates